# Max flow, min cost with upper and lower bounds

Tags: network-flow

I am trying to implement an algorithm that fairly distributes people into groups, given their ranking of those groups, while also taking into account their preference for partners.

I have modeled this as a directed graph with upper and lower bounds and costs on edges representing their ratings. Finding a solution would simply mean maximizing the flow between a source and a drain.

However finding an algorithm that can actually solve this has proven difficult. The only one I came across that seems to match all my requirements is the Out-Of-Kilter algorithm.

Literature about this algorithm is very sparse and dense though. I could also not find a good implementation of it.

I found this one https://github.com/MichalNowicki/NumericalAlgebraCodes but it seems to have some errors, since it produces solutions that do not conserve flow.

What am I missing here? Is there an easier algorithm? Is there a good implementation somewhere out there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem can be formulated as a [minimum cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem), but with lower bounds (demands) on the flow through each edge.

For details how to handle the lower bounds, see [Determine whether a flow can satisfy node demands in a directed acyclic graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125331/755) or the corresponding part of [Jeff Erickson's Algorithms textbook](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/); or see [Network flow - minimum flow through edge](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116858/755).